# Excel VBA to get a file list by multiple file extensions and last modified date

Tags: vba, excel

In my folder, I have different types of files:
**.mp4 .wav .out .outreview**

I am using a VBA code in excel to make a list of all of the files according to their file extension. As seen in the screenshot:

[image]

To do this, I use the following code four times, each time I replace the file extension and adjust the column references:

this is the example code for the first column, the video files, .mp4:

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim Desired As String

    strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\Folder\*.mp4", vbNormal)
    Range("A5:A100").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        Else
            Cells(i + 4, 1) = varDirectory
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

I repeat it for .wav and .outreview files.
But I use the following code for .out files, because, otherwise, it pulls up all the .out and . outreview files in the .out column, which I don't want.

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim Desired As String

Desired = ".out"

strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\Folder\", vbNormal)

While flag = True
    If varDirectory = "" Then
        flag = False
    Else
        If Right(varDirectory, 4) = Desired Then
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = varDirectory
            i = i + 1
        End If
        varDirectory = Dir
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

**Question:** how can I pull the last modified date **ONLY** for .out files and put them in their corresponding cells in column **D**?

And how can I combine all these codes into one code so that I don't repeat this for each file extension?
Thanks

***UPDATE***:

this update is after the answer provided by *Jeanno*:

This answers my question. here is the Jeanno's corrected version of the code.

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim Desired As String

    strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\folder\*", vbNormal)
    Range("A5:E100").clear

While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        Else
        If varDirectory Like "*.mp4" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 1) = varDirectory
        End If
        If varDirectory Like "*.wav" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 2) = varDirectory
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If varDirectory Like "*.outreview" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 5) = varDirectory
        End If
        If varDirectory Like "*.out" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 4) = varDirectory
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime("C:\Users\folder\" & varDirectory)
        End If
        varDirectory = Dir
        End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do everything in one shot. i haven't tested it. Basically I use the `Like` operator and `FileDateTime` function. Let me know if that worked for you

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim Desired As String

    strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\Folder\*", vbNormal)
    Range("A5:D100").Clear

    While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        ElseIf varDirectory Like "*.mp4" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 1) = varDirectory
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime("C:\Users\Folder\" & varDirectory)
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf varDirectory Like "*.wav" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 2) = varDirectory
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime("C:\Users\Folder\" & varDirectory)
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf varDirectory Like "*.outreview" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 5) = varDirectory
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime("C:\Users\Folder\" & varDirectory)
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf varDirectory Like "*.out" Then
            Cells(i + 4, 4) = varDirectory
            Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime("C:\Users\Folder\" & varDirectory)
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I get no results besides, i get an error for the last 'Cells(i + 4, 3) = FileDateTime(varDirectory) . How to fix this? Could you please test it yourself?

Comment: Oh, it gives NO RESPONDING. I think it goes unlimited, we gotta put a stop somewhere. Could you please suggest a fix for this?

Comment: I tried your code after I applied a few cleaning. Please find the cleaned version in my question update section. However, I get an empty cell in B5. My second column starts after an empty cell (skips one cell). Please help to fix this.

Comment: Why are you incrementing the i only at column B. My question to you is the following? Do you always expect to have the same number of file types. So for example 2 mp4, 2 wav, 2 out, 2 outreview? Also I am not sure how it will work when trying to align files on the same row.

Comment: this is strange. But the code that I put in the update section is the EXACT behaviour I am looking for. I may have different number of files per filetype, 5 mp4, 4 wav 3out 1outreview.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the modified date portion of the question, however, for the other, just include the extension in a row near the column header. Then use that to feed another loop.

so for example:

1) create a new row between rows 3 and 4.
2) in this new row 4, column A, store ".mp4". In B, ".wav", etc.
3) change your code to add another loop:
(and use that loop # to reference the proper columns)

```
  Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
      Dim varDirectory As Variant
      Dim flag As Boolean
      Dim i As Long
      Dim strDirectory As String
      Dim Desired As String

  for x = 1 to 3

  Desired = Cells(4,x).Value

  strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
  i = 1
  flag = True
  varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\Folder\", vbNormal)

  While flag = True
      If varDirectory = "" Then
          flag = False
      Else
          If Right(varDirectory, 4) = Desired Then
              Cells(i + 4, x) = varDirectory
              i = i + 1
          End If
          varDirectory = Dir
      End If
  Wend
  next x

  End Sub
```

Comment: could you please write the full code? I run into problem when I integrate your code into my own. thanks

Comment: yeah it works. But i am still looking for the last modified date/time. I am going to try other users' answers and see what comes out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
Sub M_snb()
 c00 = "C:\Users\Folder\"
 sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & c00 & "*.*"" /b/a-d").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)

 ReDim sp(1 To UBound(sn), 5)

 With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  For j = 0 To UBound(sn)
   c01 = lcase(.getextensionname(c00 & sn(j)))
   If c01 <> "" And InStr("mp4wavoutoutreview", c01) Then sp(j, Application.Match(c01, Array("mp4", "wav", "out", "", "outreview"), 0)-1) = sn(j)
   If c01 = "out" Then sp(j, 4) = FileDateTime(c00 & sn(j))
  Next
 End With

 sheet1.cells(1).resize(ubound(sp),ubound(sp,2))=sp
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error in sp(j, Application.Match(c01,.... what should I do? why is this? thanks